# Material UI useMediaQuery causes glitching/jumping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI's useMediaQuery() hook, I have injected the theme provider and have created a variable like this:

```
const theme = useTheme();
const isSmall = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm') );
```

I'm using the isSmall variable in several places to determine various characteristics of my page. Here is an example:

```
<Typography variant={isSmall ? "body2" : "h5"}>
  Case Studies
</Typography>
```

The problem I am having is that when the page first loads it renders all of the false versions of isSmall and then quickly corrects it's self causing a rather unsightly glitch.

If I remove the useMediaQuery dependancies and set the styling using the makeStyles() method everything is fine, for example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardImg: {
    opacity: 0.8,
    height: '60px',
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      height: '40px'
    }
  }
}));
```

This works fine but I don't see how I can invoke MUI style variables/variants like 'body2' and 'caption' etc without useMediaQueries.

If anyone can help I'd be appreciative.

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: are you using any theme provider?

Comment: Yes I have wrapped the root of my project in the themePrivider component

Comment: Should I be using useTheme() in the function component that I'm am having problems with?

Comment: I think instead of the ternary to choose the size of the typography have a ternary with a typography of body2 and h5

Comment: @Dandelion yes you have to inject your them provider as right now mediaquery hook doesn't have default theme support https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/

Comment: I have injected my theme provider like so `const theme = useTheme();` and updated the useMediaQuery invokation like this: `const isSmall = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm') );` an the problem still persists.

Comment: I have changed the ternary statement so that it now returns the whole component like this:

`{isSmall ? <Typography variant="body2">Case Studies</Typography> : <Typography variant="h5">Case Studies</Typography>
}` and that did not fix the problem either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. It looks like I was experiencing this issue:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21048

The solution is to use the noSsr option (as I am not server-side rendering) like this:

```
const isSmall = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'), {noSsr: true});
```

It does actually mention this in the [useMediaQuery API docs](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#api).

Thanks for your help,

Dan.

Comment: I've tried this solution but got this error: "Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server", but could work around by adding the option `{ defaultMatches: true }`